# GitHub: pre-receive hooks

Tags: github

Where can I manage pre-receive hooks on GitHub? Apparently, there is one that rejects my push, even though I am the owner of the repo and don't remember that I have set up anything of that sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with github.com, you cannot.  There are some built-in pre-receive hooks that are used.  Some of these aspects, such as protected branches, you can configure in your repository settings.  Others, such as the maximum blob size, you cannot configure.

If you're using GitHub Enterprise Server, then administrators can configure custom pre-receive hooks in addition to adjusting setting for the normal ones.  Custom pre-receive hooks are not available on github.com because GitHub doesn't want to execute users' arbitrary code that might be in a pre-receive hook (for security reasons).

Comment: Can we use same  github pre-receive hooks with AzureDevops Server?

Comment: That's a different question and you should ask it separately if there isn't already an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that one of the files exceeded the 50 MiB limit.